# C# How to return result from Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am writing a custom `InputBox` as I do not want to use the the VB box. So I would like to have the form return the result of the box when closing.

I added an overload to the form's code:

```
public InputBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public string InputBox(string LabelText, string Title, string DefaultResult)
{
    return DefaultResult;
}
```

Is that a good approach or should or can I just modify the constructor? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, for these kind of "utility" forms which are typically modal, I prefer to go the `static` route, having the constructors private. Something like:

```
private InputBox() // Constructor is private
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public static string GetValue(string LabelText, string Title, string DefaultResult)
{
    using(var form = new InputBox())
    {
       form.myLabel.Text = labelText;
       form.Text = Title;
       form.myTextBox.Text = DefaultResult;
       if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         return form.myTextBox.Text;
    }
    return DefaultResult;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
string myValue = InputBox.GetValue("foo","bar","baz");
```

---

As requested in the comments, here is some other way to do it, without using `static` methods... it's basically the same, but you relegate the handling of the form to the caller:

In your `InputBox` class:

```
private string _defaultResult;

public InputBox(string LabelText, string Title, string DefaultResult)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myLabel.Text = LabelText;
    Text = Title;
    _defaultResult = myTextBox.Text = DefaultResult;
}

public string GetValue()
{
    return this.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK ? myTextBox.Text : _defaultResult;
}
```

And on the caller:

```
string myValue = "baz";
using(var form = new InputBox("foo", "bar", myValue))
{
   form.ShowDialog();
   myValue = form.GetValue();       
}
```

Note that I don't encourage this method, since more likely the -only- reasonable way to use this form is a modal dialog, and this could potentially confuse the users of the class.

Having simple static methods (with private constructors so the form can't be instantiated by the caller in any other way) makes more sense for this, as it doesn't force the caller to know how the form is designed to be used: there's just one possible way to use it.

Comment: This looks great! Would not be the same if I overload the `InputBox`? Or you can't overload such?

Comment: Define `"overload the InputBox"`, I'm not getting you. If you mean calling your method `InputBox`, you can't do that if your class name is `InputBox`... try it: it'll give a compilation error (your example code in the question will not compile, since you can't return from a constructor and you can't name other methods like the class they belong to)

Comment: Even if you could (*which you can't*), it'd probably be a very bad thing to do... imagine you'd put your `InputBox` static method on your `InputBox` class in the `InputBox.InputBox` namespace: you'd probably need to call it like `var myValue = InputBox.InputBox.InputBox.InputBox("foo", "bar", "baz");` which would more likely be a reason for firing whoever made that code in any decent company :-)

Comment: Aha, this was exactly my question. So there is no really other way than using the static method you say.

Comment: Phew, luckily I have SO and I have you... :-)

Comment: There are other ways, you could make an instance method and have the caller show the form (instead of doing it all in a static method), but I personally don't like that for these kind of "utility" forms

Comment: Just for my own edification so I finally see a tangible example of both. Can you please refer to me that example (or can you add one like that), honestly I started on C# only recently and I still have hard time to get my wits around such concepts (after having done most of my coding in VBA)...

Comment: Sometimes I wonder: do I ask stupid questions? Hardly anybody votes them up... I think if I would find the answer to this question when searching for it (which I did and always do) I would not ask it. What do you think?

Comment: You'd probably be able to figure this one on your own taking some time to test things... it's ok if you did your research and can't get to it, and others that may have more experience may guide you in the "right" direction... as long as you are aiming for an explanation, I personally find it fine: I see a problem when people is just asking "write the code for me", many times not even trying to know how it works

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can't agree more with you! I always do my own research first. I only ask a question what I spent hours with no result... :S Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, yes, of course! But you did not vote up the question, was it so bad?

Comment: @ib11 i tend to vote more on answers... my votes on questions are reserved for those that are very well-researched or that may be exceptionally useful for other users. I *feel* that's how it should be, but it's indeed a  personal oppinion (all votes in this site are). Not upvoting doesn't mean it's bad: that's what downvoting is for. I just stand neutral: I'm not even asking for upvotes on my answer either, if you don't feel it was well-explained please don't upvote it... and mark as accepted only if it solved your problem. I'm not a bounty-hunter, just trying to make the site better for all

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying and it makes sense to me. I did accept your answer, and upvoted it because it not only solved the question but was very edifying.